# $\mathcal{O}(t^{1+\varepsilon})$ asymptotics for Brownian motion with drift

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Let $B$ be a standard Brownian motion in a filtered probability space. Assume, $K$ is bounded, adapted, continuous process and $\varepsilon > 0$. Let

$$
U_t = B_t - \int_{0}^{t}K_r ds, \quad t \geq 0
$$

Is there a choice for $K$ that ensures  $U_t = \mathcal{O}(t^{1+\varepsilon})$ for $t \to \infty$?

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathcal{O}$ here? $|U_t| \leq ct^{1+\varepsilon}$ almost surely for some deterministic $c$?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. So, the idea is that for an appropriate choice of $K$ (possibly depending on $B$), the integral acts as a sort of compensation in such way that $U_t$ exhibits the required asymptotics.

Comment: Because $|B_t|/t\to 0$ as $t\to\infty$, a.s., if $K_r(\omega)$ is uniformly bounded by a constant, then $U_t$ is $\mathcal O(t)$ as $t\to\infty$.